# Join in JPA query - spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

**Two tables**

bookings and locations

Need to join two tables with locationid (foreign key)  using joins

**Native Query**

```
SELECT l.location_name, 
b.bookingid, 
b.email, 
b.vehicle_type, 
b.vehicle_no 
FROM locations l RIGHT JOIN bookings b 
ON b.locationid = l.locationid;
```

**Bookings** Table Entity

```
@Entity
public class Bookings {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer bookingid;
    private String email;
    private String vehicle_type;
    private String  vehicle_no;
    private String date;
    private String time;
    private Integer duration;
    private String cost = "0";
    private Integer locationid;
    private String slotid;
    private Integer paid = 0;
}
```

**Locations** Table Entity

```
@Entity
public class Locations {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer locationid;
    private String location_name;
    private Integer slots = 0;
    private String area;    
}
```

**Expected Output**

```
+---------------+-----------+------------------+---------------+--------------+
| location_name | bookingid |      email       |  vehicle_no   | vehicle_type |
+--------------}-+-----------+------------------+---------------+--------------+
| Pothys        |        22 | test05@gmail.com | TN-01-AA-123  | Four Wheeler |
| Brook Fields  |        25 | test05@gmail.com | TN-01-AA-1111 | Two Wheeler  |
+---------------+-----------+------------------+---------------+--------------+
```

How to implement in spring,
Some one help me out...
Thank you.

Comment: Add a Location object instead of locationId field in bookings. Put a @manytoone relation in bookings to location. Retrieve your booking objects as needed in your dao, like this entityManager.createQuery("from Bookings").getResultList();, and you've done.Here an example https://www.infoworld.com/article/3373652/java-persistence-with-jpa-and-hibernate-part-1-entities-and-relationships.html?page=3

Comment: @emotionlessbananas i have tried what Massimo said
But i dont know the exact syntax as im newbie to java and spring

Comment: start here: https://vladmihalcea.com/sql-join-using/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you must define the relationships in your entity, as follows:

Define relation many to one in Bookings

```
@Entity
public class Bookings {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer bookingid;
    private String email;
    private String vehicle_type;
    private String  vehicle_no;
    private String date;
    private String time;
    private Integer duration;
    private String cost = "0";

    // change this
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="locationid")
    private Locations location;

    private String slotid;
    private Integer paid = 0;
}
```

Define the bidirectional relationship in locations

```
@Entity
public class Locations {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer locationid;
    private String location_name;
    private Integer slots = 0;
    private String area;    

    // add this
    // you can use Set instead of List
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="location",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Bookings> bookings;
}
```

Once the entities are modeled, we proceed to make the query, I don't know what implementation you use, in this example I am going to do it with Criteria API:

As we cannot implement right join, we will substitute for inner join which will return the same result.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<YourPojo> cq = cb.createQuery(YourPojo.class);

Root<Locations> rootLocations = cq.from(Location.class);
Join<Locations,Bookings> joinBookings = rootLocations.join(Locations_.bookings,JoinType.INNER);
// If you don't use metamodel change Locations_.bookings for rootLocations.get("bookings")

cq.multiselect(
    rootLocations.get(Locations_.location_name),
    joinBookings.get(Bookings_.bookingid),
    joinBookings.get(Bookings_.email),
    joinBookings.get(Bookings_.vehicle_type),
    joinBookings.get(Bookings_.vehicle_no)
);
//If you don't use metamodel change it as in join

List<YourPojo> results = entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

You will need a well to obtain the data, which has a constructor with the same parameters as the criteria multiselect, with the same order and the same type

```
public YourPojo(String location_name,Integer bookingid,String email, String vehicle_type, String vehicle_no){
    [...]
}
```